# Adding Collision Object in MoveIt

Tags: ros, transforms, moveit, collision-object, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have written a node to add a wall as a collision object in moveit.

This is my node :

```
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
#include <moveit/planning_scene_interface/planning_scene_interface.h>
#include <geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h>

using namespace Eigen; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "add_wall");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::AsyncSpinner spin(1);
    spin.start();

    moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface current_scene;
    sleep(2.0);
    
    Vector3d b(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
    moveit_msgs::CollisionObject co;
    co.id = "wall";
    shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://mitsubishi_rv6sd_support/meshes/wall.stl",b); 
    ROS_INFO("Wall mesh loaded");

    shape_msgs::Mesh mesh;
    shapes::ShapeMsg mesh_msg;  
    shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m, mesh_msg);
    mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(mesh_msg);

    co.meshes.resize(1);
    co.mesh_poses.resize(1);
    co.meshes[0] = mesh;
    co.header.frame_id = "wall";   
    co.mesh_poses[0].position.x = 0.560651;
    co.mesh_poses[0].position.y = 0.579113;
    co.mesh_poses[0].position.z = 0.0;
    co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 1.0; 
    co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0.0; 
    co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 0.0;
    co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= 0.0;   

    co.meshes.push_back(mesh);
    co.mesh_poses.push_back(co.mesh_poses[0]);
    co.operation = co.ADD;
    std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> vec;
    vec.push_back(co);
    ROS_INFO("Wall added into the world");
    current_scene.addCollisionObjects(vec);
    sleep(5.0);
    ros::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

---

When I run the node after running demo.launch, I am able to see the wall along with my robot in RViZ. But I get the following error :

```
[ INFO] [1476879844.724728125]: Wall mesh loaded
[ INFO] [1476879844.724948036]: Wall added into the world

[ERROR] [1476879844.947753744]: Unable to transform from frame 'wall' to frame '/base_link'. Returning identity.

[add_wall-10] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/sbr/.ros/log/eaf6e28a-95f6-11e6-9e7f-480fcf447f3c/add_wall-10*.log
```

I was trying to add this as a `static_transform_publisher` in the demo.launch file

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_wall" args=" 0.560651 0.579113 0 0 0 0 base_link wall 100" />
```

But this doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245995/adding-collision-object-in-moveit/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html), you will find that in the header you don't want to put the id of the object, but the reference frame. This will probably be something like "world" but it depends on your configuration.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-10-19**:
I have a `/base_link` frame which is the robot's frame. I am using that as reference for collision objects. Following the moveit tutorials, I have created a virtual joint called `world_joint` between the world and base_link frame. I am changing the header to `/base_link`. Is that alright?